# How do I use a join to query two tables and get all rows from one, and related rows from the other?

Tags: sql, join

Simplified for example, I have two tables, `groups` and `items`.

```
items (
    id,
    groupId,
    title
)

groups (
    id,
    groupTitle,
    externalURL
)
```

The regular query I'm goes something like this:

```
SELECT
    i.`id`,
    i.`title`,
    g.`id` as 'groupId',
    g.`groupTitle`,
    g.`externalURL`
FROM
    items i INNER JOIN groups g ON (i.`groupId` = g.`id`)
```

However I need to modify this now, because all the groups which specify an `externalURL` will not have any corresponding records in the `items` table (since they're stored externally). Is it possible to do some sort of join so that the output looks kinda like this:

```
items:
id    title    groupId
----------------------
1     Item 1   1
2     Item 2   1

groups
id    groupTitle    externalURL
-------------------------------
1     Group 1       NULL
2     Group 2       something
3     Group 3       NULL

Query output:
id    title    groupId    groupTitle    externalURL
---------------------------------------------------
1     Item 1   1          Group 1       NULL
2     Item 2   1          Group 1       NULL
NULL  NULL     2          Group 2       something

-- note that group 3 didn't show up because it had no items OR externalURL
```

Is that possible in one SQL query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is exactly what an outer join is for:  return all the rows from one table, whether or not there is a matching row in the other table.  In those cases, return NULL for all the columns of the other table.

The other condition you can take care of in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    i.`id`,
    i.`title`,
    g.`id` as 'groupId',
    g.`groupTitle`,
    g.`externalURL`
FROM
    items i RIGHT OUTER JOIN groups g ON (i.`groupId` = g.`id`)
WHERE i.`id` IS NOT NULL OR g.`externalURL` IS NOT NULL;
```

Only if *both* `i.id` and `g.externalURL` are NULL, then the whole row of the joined result set should be excluded.

Comment: I guess I should have listened more in Databases 101, hey? Cheers.